# Incapsula - How do I allow socket connection/requests from a specific IP?

Tags: apache, incapsula

I am not very familiar with Incapsula but I am currently working in a project that needs to send socket messages using simple socket php scripts on both ends (scripts work in localhost):

-Client:
Outside Incapsula
Sends messages to server

-Server:
Apache
Inside Incapsula (under Incapsula protection)
Receives messages from client (a single client)

Supposing the IP from the client is: 198.168.123.123, how should I proceed to allow connections from this IP as if the server had no Incapsula protection for this IP?

Or is it impossible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's always recommended to restrict server access to Incapsula IPs:
   https://incapsula.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200627570-Restricting-direct-access-to-your-website-Incapsula-s-IP-addresses-
2. You can restrict the client's source IP inside your Incapsula account very easily:
   www.incapsula.com/demo/settings_3.html
3. If you want to restrict it in your code, you can use X-Forwarded-For and/or Incap-Client-IP headers:
   https://incapsula.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200627650-The-IPs-in-my-weblogs-have-changed

HTH,
Ofer

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I gave the overall answer here, and it's very concise. as far as invalid answers go - on the contrary, these things change (e.g. IP ranges), so it's better to have an up2date answer from the FAQ than an obsolete one here.